# Help Understanding Why This Mathematical Is Wrong?

Tags: probability

I have the following question:

- How many times on average do you need to roll a pair dice before you get a $1$ followed by another $1$ ?
- How many times on average do you need to roll a pair of dice before you get a $1$ followed by a $2$?

Here is the logic:

- The probability of rolling a $1$ is $\frac16$
- The probability of rolling a $2$ is also $\frac16$
- The probability of rolling a $(1,2)$ or $(1,1)$ is $\frac1{36}$
- This means that out of every $36$ rolls, you will be expected to see a $(1,1)$ or a $(1,2)$
- Therefore, you can expect to roll a dice 36 times before you get $(1,1)$ or $(1,2)$

But in reality, this logic is said not to be correct.

Using Markov Chains (i.e. time to absorption until 4,6 is reached), we can show that a $(4,6)$ takes $36$ rolls on average, whereas a $(6,6)$ takes $42$ rolls on average.

How can I reconcile both of these mathematical statements?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not clear.  If $(a,b)$ denotes the ordered outcome of the roll of two distinguished  fair dice, then each of the $36$ pairs is equally probable, so each has probability $\frac 1{36}$ so you expect it to take $36$ rolls to see any particular outcome.  Not sure what "Markov Chain" you have in mind.

Comment: Your statements are a bit unclear. Are the two dice distinguished? Or are we looking at the outcome on the pair of dice? For starters, a (4,6) might have also been a (6,4). So you have twice the chance of getting $(a,b)$ when $b\ne a$ as you do of getting $(a,a)$. By the way, *die* is singular and *dice* is plural.

Comment: You started with $(1,1)$ vs $(1,2)$, then switched to $(4,6)$ vs $(6,6)$. Please edit your question to give clarity to the question.

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  I can't tell whether you are tossing a pair of distinct dice, a pair of indistinct dice, or a single die repeatedly.  It looks like you are garbling together a number of vaguely related problems, but it isn't clear what the actual question is.  Why not just say clearly and precisely what a single trial of your experiment looks like?

Comment: Rolling a pair of dice

Comment: Then why do you say "How many times on average do you need to roll a dice before you get a 1 followed by another 1?" That sounds like you are repeatedly tossing a single die.  Worth noting that $42$ and $36$ are the correct answers for *that* problem ($42$ for a double like $(6,6)$ and $36$ for a mismatched set like $(1,2)$.

Comment: @ lulu: my appologies, I will try to make these corrections. I get confused

Comment: @ lulu: i made these changes

Comment: I suggest:  pick a particular, specific question of the type you are interested in and write out a trial completely and explicitly, showing the exact count that trial would give.  That ought to clarify the rules.

Comment: @ lulu : if you have time, can you please explain why my logic is wrong for this problem I described?

Comment: Post edit:  Sorry, still not clear.  if you are rolling a pair of dice, what does it mean for one outcome to "follow" another?  If you roll a red die and a blue one, and the red one gets you a $3$ and the blue one gets you a $6$, which one followed the other?

Comment: If you are tossing a pair of dice then you can speak about the *ordered* outcome, if the dice are distinct, or the *unordered* outcome if the dice are indistinguishable (or if you are just ignoring the fact that you can tell them apart).  It matters which sort you consider...if you look at ordered rolls, then $(1,2)$ has a probability of $\frac 1{36}$.  Indeed, every combination has that probability.  If you look at unordered rolls, then $\{1,2\}$ has a probability of $\frac 2{36}=\frac 1{18}$.

Comment: But, really, I think you mean to roll a single die repeatedly.  Then it is true that you expect it to take $42$ trials to see a fixed matched pair and $36$ trials to see an unmatched pair.  The difference comes from the fact that, in the unmatched case, if you have tossed the first of the desired pair then you might toss that same value again without winning and without returning to the start.  In the matched case, that can't happen.

Answer (score 4):

Now that you have edited the question, I understand you are asking why number of die rolls to get $1$ followed by $1$ is not the same as number of die rolls to get $1$ followed by a $2$, and you don't want to go through the Markov process

In simple terms,
for $1$ followed by $1$, if you fail on the second try, you go back to *start*,
wheras for $1$ followed by $2$, failing on the next attempt has a $1/6$ probability that you *remain at* $1$, not go back to start, so you will require fewer rolls.

Answer (score 1):

> How many times on average do you need to roll a dice before you get a (1,1)?

Let $p(n)$ denote the probability that it takes exactly $n$ rolls to get a (1,1).

Then, the average number of rolls needed is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[n \times p(n)\right].$$

To compute $p(n)$ you have to consider two events:

- In the first $(n-1)$ rolls, you fail to get (1,1).
  The probability of this happening in $\displaystyle \left[\frac{35}{36}\right]^{n-1}.$
- Then, on the $n$-th roll, you get (1,1).
  The probability of this happening in $\displaystyle \left[\frac{1}{36}\right].$

Therefore, the average number of rolls needed is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ ~n \times \left[\frac{35}{36}\right]^{n-1} \times \frac{1}{36} ~\right\}. \tag1 $$

Temporarily ignoring the constant, $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{36},~$ and setting $~T = \frac{35}{36},~$ the expression 
$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ ~n \times \left[\frac{35}{36}\right]^{n-1} ~\right\}$

can be re-expressed as

$$1 \times [1 + T + T^2 + T^3 + \cdots]$$

$$+ 1 \times [T + T^2 + T^3 + \cdots]$$

$$+ 1 \times [T^2 + T^3 + \cdots]$$

$$+ 1 \times [T^3 + \cdots]$$

$$+ \cdots.$$

Since $[1 + T + T^2 + T^3 + \cdots]$ equals $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-T},~$ the above computations can be re-expressed as

$$\frac{1}{1-T} \times [1 + T + T^2 + T^3 + \cdots] = \left[\frac{1}{1-T}\right]^2.$$

Therefore, the average number of rolls needed equals

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ ~n \times \left[\frac{35}{36}\right]^{n-1} \times \frac{1}{36} ~\right\} $$

$$= \frac{1}{36} \times \frac{1}{\left[1 - \frac{35}{36}\right]^2} = 36.$$

> How many times on average do you need to roll a dice before you get a (1,2)?

Assuming that there is one red die and one green die, and assuming that this question intends **either** of the events:

- red=1, green=2
- red=2, green=1

Then the method that I used for the first question also applies to this second question.  The only difference is that the probability of $~\dfrac{1}{36}~$ is replaced by $~\dfrac{2}{36} = \dfrac{1}{18}.$

Therefore, for question 2, the average number of rolls needed is $18.$

---

**Addendum**

I was going to attack the Math in the revised problem.  However,

- Apparently, the OP has already done this, given his reference to Markov chains.
- The (intuitive) *reconciliation* question that the OP is asking has been answered by the response of true blue anil.

Comment: The question is very poorly phrased, but I believe that the OP is asking "suppose we roll a fair die repeatedly, seeking a given  ordered pair on consecutive terms.  If the pair is distinct, like $1,2$ then you expect it to take $36$ turns, while if the pair is a double, like $6,6$ then you expect it to take $42$ turns.  Yet on any given two throws you are equally likely to see $1,2$ or $6,6$.  How do we reconcile this?"  I could be wrong...the OP has so far declined to add clarity.

Comment: The OP is editing the post now...maybe my interpretation was wrong, though I doubt it since the official answers they mention match my version (and not the other versions, so far as I can tell).